# Error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosf' when using cURL

Tags: c++, c, curl

I am trying to learn about cURL and found some code online that I wanted to compile in Visual Studio but I get a series of strange errors. I tried googling the errors but couldn't find any that related to my issue. I installed cURL libraries okay but when I try to run this program:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

// callback function writes data to a std::ostream
static size_t data_write(void* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp)
{
    if(userp)
    {
        std::ostream& os = *static_cast<std::ostream*>(userp);
        std::streamsize len = size * nmemb;
        if(os.write(static_cast<char*>(buf), len))
            return len;
    }

    return 0;
}

/**
 * timeout is in seconds
 **/
CURLcode curl_read(const std::string& url, std::ostream& os, long timeout = 30)
{
    CURLcode code(CURLE_FAILED_INIT);
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl)
    {
        if(CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &data_write))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, &os))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout))
        && CURLE_OK == (code = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str())))
        {
            code = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return code;
}

int main()
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    std::ofstream ofs("output.html");
    if(CURLE_OK == curl_read("http://google.com", ofs))
    {
        // Web page successfully written to file
    }

    std::ostringstream oss;
    if(CURLE_OK == curl_read("http://google.com", oss))
    {
        // Web page successfully written to string
        std::string html = oss.str();
    }

    if(CURLE_OK == curl_read("http://google.com", std::cout))
    {
        // Web page successfully written to standard output (console?)
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

I get the following list of errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cURL.c, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.c
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xtgmath.h(111): warning C4602: #pragma pop_macro : 'new' no previous #pragma push_macro for this identifier
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xtgmath.h(112): warning C4193: #pragma warning(pop) : no matching '#pragma warning(push)'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xtgmath.h(113): warning C4161: #pragma pack(pop...) : more pops than pushes
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(28): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(28): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(28): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'asinf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atanf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atan2f'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(29): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ceilf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cosf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'coshf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(30): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'expf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(31): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fabsf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(31): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(31): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'floorf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(31): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fmodf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'frexpf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ldexpf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(32): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'logf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'log10f'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'modff'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(33): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'powf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(34): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sinf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(34): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(34): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sinhf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(34): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sqrtf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(35): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tanf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(35): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(35): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tanhf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(37): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(37): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(37): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'asinl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(38): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atanl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(38): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(38): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atan2l'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(38): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ceill'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(39): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cosl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(39): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(39): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'coshl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(39): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'expl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(40): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fabsl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(40): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(40): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'floorl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(40): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fmodl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(41): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'frexpl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(41): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(41): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ldexpl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(41): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'logl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(42): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'log10l'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(42): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(42): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'modfl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(42): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'powl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(43): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sinl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(43): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(43): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sinhl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(43): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sqrtl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(44): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tanl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(44): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(44): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tanhl'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(46): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'abs'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(46): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(48): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acos'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(48): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(48): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'asin'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(49): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atan'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(49): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(49): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atan2'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(49): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ceil'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(50): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cos'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(50): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(50): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cosh'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(50): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'exp'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(51): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fabs'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(51): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(51): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'floor'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(51): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fmod'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(52): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'frexp'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(52): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(52): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ldexp'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(52): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'log'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(53): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'log10'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(53): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(53): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'modf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(53): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'pow'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(54): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sin'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(54): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(54): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sinh'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(54): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'sqrt'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(55): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tan'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(55): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(55): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tanh'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(57): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'hypot'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(57): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cmath(57): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'hypotf'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cstdio(36): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cstdio(38): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'using'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cstdio(38): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cstdio(39): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'clearerr'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cstdio(39): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cstdio(39): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'fclose'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\cstdio(39): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What could be the problem?

EDIT:
program without errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
//#include <curl.h>
//#include <curlbuild.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
    // example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection  
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    // Perform the request, res will get the return code  
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    // Check for errors  
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    // always cleanup  
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your cURL library is trying to use C99 `float` functions that are not provided by your compiler's runtime library.  C89 defines `acos()`; C99 defines `acosf()` and `acosl()` too, but you don't have them available to you.

You'll either need to find out how to compile cURL so it doesn't expect to use those functions, or you'll have to write them:

    float acosf(float x) { return acos(x); }

Rinse and repeat — ad nauseam.  You'll then have to fix your link line to pick up your functions after the cURL library has been linked.
(Comment added, deleted, readded...)

Comment: Sorry about confusing by commenting, answering, and then reversing decisions on you. My bad! You ask "Is there a way to include those functions so the compiler can see them? Can't I download them somewhere?" — Reasonable question: I don't know whether there's somewhere to download them from. I'm not quite sure what's going on, on a closer look. You have syntax errors where I was diagnosing link time errors — so the problem isn't quite what I thought it was. Nevertheless, MSVC is a C89 compiler, not a C99 or C11 compiler, so it is related to the problem I stated, but not exactly what I stated.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No problem, I guess I deserve this headache for using Windows on the first place. I just can't believe that Microsoft wouldn't support something as important as this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is there a way to modify the program so that it is not calling these C99 functions but retains its functionality?

Comment: It's strange that all the errors are in Microsoft's headers. I would guess that something in the curl headers is clashing with something in the MS headers. Have you tried switching the order of the header files?

Comment: @john I don't have the actual header files since I included the files via a "VC++ Directories" tab under "Include Directories".

Comment: @YuriSwarovski I mean you put `#include <curl/curl.h>` first in your code, try putting it last. Might help diagnostically, even if it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @john I tried every permutation, and the errors are still there.

Comment: @YuriSwarovski Are they there when you exclude `#include <curl/curl.h>`? I beginning to wonder if you've messed up your compiler installation somehow. None of the error messages refer to an curl header, it's all microsoft headers it seems to me. Or did you try to install curl into the microsoft directories?

Comment: @john yes they are, what should I do?

Comment: @YuriSwarovski Try creating a new project, see if that also has problems. If so then I think you are just going to have to reinstall your compiler. Then reinstall curl, but this time don't try to install it in the same place as your compiler.

Comment: @YuriSwarovski Maybe there's a name clash between a curl header and an MS header. Unfortunate if true. In VC++ directories the curl directories should go after the MS directories.

Comment: @john The program I added as an edit above gives no errors and uses curl and my other programs work, so I don't think that the compiler is corrupted and needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: @YuriSwarovski Hang on, I've just noticed something, you are compiling a file called main.c, but it is clearly C++ code. Change the name of the file  to main.cpp!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is that you are compiling C++ code as C. Change the name of your file to main.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including math.h?
I use Visual Studio 2012 and I can use the float functions.

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer.